# nonmatching groups in Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script

https://jsfiddle.net/sbzxd5ya/1/ - Here is a javascript which works where I try to extract some values from a column in a array using regular expression.

But when I try same google app script i get - SyntaxError: Unmatched ) in regular expression for var - splitter

```
function getSpreadsheetData61() {
var data6 = [
  ["id", "name", "count", "Category"],
  ["1", "g", "8", "[(P2, 7), (P1, 1)]"],
  ["2", "g", "8", "[(P0, 7), (P2, 1)]"],
  ["2", "g", "8", "[(P0, 7), (P2, 1),(P1,5)]"],
  ["3", "g", "8", "[()]"],
  ["4", "t", "4", "[(P2, 4)]"]
];

var output=[];
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
var row = data6[i];
data6.map(function(row) {
  var toExpand = row[row.length - 1];
  var indices = new RegExp('/\(?:\\(P)(\d)/','g');
  var splitter = new RegExp('/(\d)(?:\))','g');
  var extracted;
  var eIndex;
  Logger.log(splitter);

  toAdd = [0, 0, 0];
  while (extracted = splitter.exec(toExpand)) {
    eIndex = indices.exec(toExpand);
    toAdd[eIndex[1]] = extracted[1];


  }
  //Logger.log(eIndex);
  output.push(row.concat(toAdd));

});

 }
Logger.log(output);
  return data6;
}
```

Can some one help to fix the issue and get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-capturing groups are [broken in Google Apps Script](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=842) with the status "WontFix":

> The engineering team decided not to take action on this issue.

So, don't use them. They play no role in your regexes, anyway.

Another issue,  indicating either a broken regex engine or incorrect loop optimization, is that the lastIndex property of your regex `indices` does not get reset to zero when you assign indices with `var indices = ...`. (I suspect this is because this assignment get "optimized" out of the loop.) So, reset it manually:

```
  var indices = /\(P(\d)/g;
  indices.lastIndex = 0;
  var splitter = /(\d)\)/g;
```

Then the script works correctly.

---

Test example for the lastIndex issue:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var re = /a/g;
    Logger.log(re.lastIndex);
    re.exec('aaa');
  }
```

outputs 0, 1, 2 in Google Apps Script. In a browser, the output would be 0, 0, 0.

---

Last remark, regarding a syntax issue.  For some reason you decided to build regular expressions from strings using `new RegExp(string)` instead of regex literals used in the fiddle. To do so correctly you need to pay double attention to escaping: there is escaping on the regex level, and then there's escaping on the string level.  Long story short,

```
var splitter = new RegExp('/(\d)(?:\))','g');
```

should be

```
var splitter = new RegExp('/(\\d)(?:\\))','g');
```

because every backslash that you want to appear in the regex must be a double backslash in the string. It would be easier to use a regex literal: you don't need to escape backslashes in it, though forward slashes now must be escaped:

```
var splitter = /\/(\d)(?:\))/g
```

Comment: Even after fixing it.. I don't get the expected output.

Comment: Your `indices` regex has a similar issue.

Comment: var indices = new RegExp('/\(?:\\(P)(\\d)/','g');
    var splitter = new RegExp('/(\\d)(?:\\))','g');

Comment: I changed both the regular expression as follows and the output I see is -  id, name, count, Category, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1, g, 8, [(P2, 7), (P1, 1)], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2, g, 8, [(P0, 7), (P2, 1)], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2, g, 8, [(P0, 7), (P2, 1),(P1,5)], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [3, g, 8, [()], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [4, t, 4, [(P2, 4)], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

Comment: I mean it works fine in JS script. But not in Google app script even after fixing the regular expression. Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the my regular expression in Google Apps script